# Generate physical file fo bundle in bundleconfig.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I have around 100 bundles in my bundleconfig.cs file like below. How can I generate physical file for below bundle

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryall")
   .IncludeDirectory("~/scripts/jquery", "*.js", true)
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryall")
   .IncludeDirectory("~/scripts/admin", "*.js", true)
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryall")
   .IncludeDirectory("~/scripts/user", "*.js", true)
....
....
....
```

Why do I need to physical file for the bundle?

I have MVC application for on-premises deployment where I don't need a physical file for each bundle.

Now, I am planning to provide my App as SaaS as well. so for the performance consideration, I want to deliver it from CDN.

As said above, I already have around 100 bundles in my app, so I am looking for easier way to generate the physical file for all those bundles from BundleConfig.cs, by this way I can have single BundleConfig.cs and have support for on-premises and SaaS for my application.

Updated

Yes, I can do open bundle link in browse and save them, but what if I made changes in core js which is referred to all bundle then I need to open those 100 bundle again in the browser to get minified content which makes development for SaaS more time-consuming. I am looking easier which is now available at asp.net core application

Comment: as you mention you want SaaS application than do you mean there is different js for each tenant? and do you want to load as tenant request?

Comment: @programtreasures No there is no tenants specific bundle. js is common for all tenants

Answer (score 2):

You can add your require files to a bundle `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` and load to the browser, and get link of your created bundle. Now save your file from your bundle link and deploy it to your CDN.

Now below code is to access CDN file using bundling, Remember you cannot mix any other local or CDN file to a single bundle,

Example code to add CDN link in bundle config

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    //            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support

    //add link to jquery on the CDN
    var jqueryCdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",
            jqueryCdnPath).Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

// Code removed for clarity.
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can do like this, but what if I made changes in core js which is referred to all bundle then I need to open those 100 bundle again in the browser to get minified content. I am looking easier which is now available at asp.net core application.

Comment: yes correct, if you are changing in core js you must push to your CDN. I dont belive than any feature related to .net core for such requirement.